# Why is the result of code snippt is not true according the define about classmethod in python(2.7)?

Tags: python-2.7

```
class Pizza(object):
   radius = 2
   @classmethod
   def get_radius(self):
      return self.radius
>>>print Pizza.get_radius is Pizza().get_radius 
   False
```

I think the result is True,because the classmedthod belongs to the class object.

Comment: `Pizza().get_radius == Pizza.get_radius` evaluates to `True`

Comment: Oh, thank you, but why?  because they have  different memory id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you instanciate `Pizza` you get a `get_radius` function which has a different id but points to the same code:

```
>>> id(Pizza().get_radius)
50027464
>>> id(Pizza.get_radius)
41275656
```

ok the refs are different but the contents are the same:

```
>>> Pizza.get_radius.__func__ is Pizza().get_radius.__func__
True
```

the function objects are the same and using `==` also yields `True`:

```
>>> Pizza().get_radius == Pizza.get_radius
True
```

So, like when comparing strings or integers, or whatever, it's better to avoid `is` because it's too much implementation dependent, with minimal benefits (except for the singletons like `None`)

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> Pizza.get_radius()
2

>>> Pizza().get_radius
<bound method type.get_radius of <class 'Pizza'>>
```

When you type `Pizza.get_radius()`,you call the function and you get your result.
When you type `Pizza().get_radius` ,first of all you initiate a new Pizza object and you don't call the function really.

Comment: check again `Pizza.get_radius is Pizza().get_radius `: do you see a function call?